# How to use addTarget method in swift 3. Convert 2.3 to 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

Convert code 2.3 to 3.0 now this line of code create crash check my code and tell me where I'm wrong

```
let activeRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

activeRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh:"), for: .valueChanged)

func refresh(control:UIRefreshControl) {

    self.ExchangeData()
}
```

Comment: Why are you still using `Selector(...)`? It's deprecated since Swift 2.2. Find old Xcode (7.3.1) and migrate your code to Swift 2.2. And after that, use Xcode 8. Migrators would do it for you.

Comment: can you write down in swift 3.0 this line activeRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("refresh:"), for: .valueChanged)

Comment: Read my comment. Use Xcode 7 and follow the shown suggestion.

Comment: thanks sir now code work for me activeRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(control:)),for: .valueChanged)